# My bathroom door stays open in summer

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question, temperature, everyday-life

My bathroom door remains open in summer, but in the winter it stays about halfway between fully open (90 degree angle, against a window) and closed. The door is between bedroom and bathroom and it is close to an exterior wall. Temperatures in summer are usually in the 80s (Fahrenheit) and in winter 20s - 30s. The door is wood, painted white. Does anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: My first instinct is that temperature differences cause the material in your door to grow/shrink, causing the equilibrium position to vary. Since your door is wood, it might also grow/shrink from moisture differences.

Comment: Not just the door, but the structure of the whole house will expand and contract. It doesn't take much of a differential somewhere to cause a little tilting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on homeowners.SE (or whatever that site's called)

Comment: In my judgment, this has more to do with humidity than temperature.  The outside temperature during the winter is certainly not transmitted to your bathroom door because your house is heated.  But the absolute humidity of the air in your house is much lower in the winter than in the summer.  Your door water content is at equilibrium with the water vapor in the air.  So there is a change in the weight distribution of your door between winter and summer.  You can test this hypothesis by putting a humidifier in the bathroom during winter.